# installation and configuration of james server on local host

Tags: windows, apache, email, james

i tried google, youtube for some kind of demo's or instructions .. but couldn't find any..
i tried going through the james server's website and i also tried some article on ibm
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1/index.html

but everything in vain..
i am new to these things and i am trying to host a mail server on my machine to send mails using php code..
i downloaded a source package of stable version of james from

http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_James_2.3.2_is_the_stable_version

the instructions i found told me to redirect to james/bin and run a file called run.bat

but when i run it all i get is

using phoenix home
using phoenix tmpdir
using java home

and then
shutting sown
phoenix 4.2

i am installing it on windows 7

can someone help me out with it please..

Comment: use version 3.  On Linux, you have to run as root, dunno about windows.  Navigate the james folder and try the following `bin/james help`, `bin/james console`, and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: thanks @Thufir but i have windows installed. 
i will try it :)

Comment: you need to copy and paste the entire error message, not just "shutting down."  also, why not use v3?

Answer (score 0):

According to described symptoms I suppose that you downloaded wrong version (smth like as [james-x.x.x-src.zip](http://apache-mirror.telesys.org.ua//james/server/apache-james-2.3.2-src.zip)).
In your case (windows 7) you need other one **james-binary-x.x.x.zip**
[james-binary-x.x.x.zip](http://apache-mirror.telesys.org.ua//james/server/apache-james-2.3.2.zip) has the same easy installation. Just unzip files under any directory. launch [INSTALLDIR]\bin\run.bat